# CNTK usage to create c# application

Tags: voice, speech, cntk, cortana

I am new to cognitive toolkit and still exploring how to use it. But I can hardly find any resources or videos on how to use cognitive toolkit to create an application. I am looking to build speech recognition and navigation application similar to Cortana or siri. Any pointers as to how to use cognitive toolkit with visual studio application would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [CNTK Evaluation Overview](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/wiki/CNTK-Evaluation-Overview) to find the right evaluation method for your application. The `CNTK-library` provides most features and supports the `model-v2` format.
You can find `C++` and `C#` evaluation examples [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/tree/master/Examples/Evaluation). Language understanding examples are also included in the GitHub repository, but written in `Python` and `BrainScript`.

Answer (score 0):

While CNTK is an awesome deep learning toolkit, it may be difficult to start with if you are not familiar with the basic machine learning concepts. It contains ample examples on designing and consuming a deep learning algorithm/network. However, if you are not really after building and training your own network, you can also have a look at [Cognitive Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/services/cognitive-services/). It has well-trained deep learning networks and are being offered as a service. These are also easy to consume, when you are thinking about building an application on top of it.